# Merging one client-side junk email filter with another, learning from each other

Tags: spam-prevention

I have my desktop email client which is teaching a filter about junk emails, and I am also using the same filter in another machine.

I want then to take the learnings of both filters and merge them into a big one.

A server based filter might do the work, but I am looking for a client-side solution.

How do I get one spam filter to merge with another so both can know about each other's rules to processing junk mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Spambayes** will let you copy its database to other machines and according to [this forum post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/spambayes/2004-March/011933.html) you can merge databases with a provided script.

http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/faq.html#can-i-share-move-my-training-data-from-one-computer-to-another